# Using required modules in Browserify Diffrently

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify, uppy

First  I bundled my main.js file with bundle.js

my main.js:

```html
const Uppy = require('@uppy/core');
const XHRUpload = require('@uppy/xhr-upload');
const Dashboard = require('@uppy/dashboard');
const Webcam = require('@uppy/webcam');
const ImageEditor = require('@uppy/image-editor')

const uppy = new Uppy({
    id: 'uppy',
    autoProceed: false,
    restrictions: {
        maxFileSize: null,
        minFileSize: null,
        maxTotalFileSize: null,
        maxNumberOfFiles: null,
        minNumberOfFiles: null,
        allowedFileTypes: null
      }
     
}).use(Dashboard,{
    inline: true,
    target:'#drag-drop-area',
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
   
})
.use(XHRUpload,{
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/image',
    fieldName:'photo',
    formData: true
})
.use(Webcam,{target:Dashboard})
.use(ImageEditor, {
    target: Dashboard,
    quality: 0.8
  });
```

Now I want this part from my main.js file to be different for different pages in my website
(for example **endpoints,maxsFileSize** etc)  :-

```html
const uppy = new Uppy({
    id: 'uppy',
    autoProceed: false,
    restrictions: {
        maxFileSize: null,
        minFileSize: null,
        maxTotalFileSize: null,
        maxNumberOfFiles: null,
        minNumberOfFiles: null,
        allowedFileTypes: null
      }
     
}).use(Dashboard,{
    inline: true,
    target:'#drag-drop-area',
    width: 700,
    height: 400,
   
})
.use(XHRUpload,{
    endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/image',
    fieldName:'photo',
    formData: true
})
.use(Webcam,{target:Dashboard})
.use(ImageEditor, {
    target: Dashboard,
    quality: 0.8
  });

console.log('puuppy');
```

**How do I do that. Please help..!!**
I read about *--standalone* but didn't how to apply it to my problem

Comment: So you want the variable uppy can be exported to other files and can have different results with parameters you want to put?

Comment: Yes can you answer please

Comment: @jacobkim  can you answer please

Comment: So in that case the main.js file should have different endpoints, maxsFileSize for each web page.

Comment: see that the case *uppy* doesnt allow multiple endpoints

Comment: all I want to do is create two main.js type file and include them seaprately for concerned page  instead of bundle.js